# cronで@rebootが動作しません。

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, python3, cron

はじめまして
Linux初心者です、ネット上に類似案件が見当たらなかったので質問させていただきます。

ラズパイ上で

```
sudo crontab -e
```

からエディタを起動し、

```
10 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/seminar/room-pub.py;
```

と設定するとPythonが動くのですが、上記を

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/seminar/room-pub.py;
```

と設定しても再起動時に動いてくれません。

どのような確認をすべきでしょうか？
cron.logは以下のようになっております。

■正常に動作時

```
Jun 12 16:34:01 raspberrypi CRON[1695]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/seminar/room-pub.py;)
```

■@reboot　設定時

```
Jun 12 17:17:07 raspberrypi cron[412]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jun 12 17:17:07 raspberrypi cron[412]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jun 12 17:17:07 raspberrypi CRON[464]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/seminar/room-pub.py;)
Jun 12 17:17:09 raspberrypi CRON[423]: (root) MAIL (mailed 785 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 from MTA#012)
```

以上になります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

※追記
@take88 様　@masm 様
ご指摘ありがとうございます。

- `/var/spool/mail/root`　を確認してみましたが、ファイルが存在しませんでした。
- 末尾の「`;`」を削除してみましたが改善されませんでした。
- `@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/seminar/room-pub.py > /tmp/room-pub.log 2>&1` に変更してみました、出力されたコードが以下になるのですが、末尾行にエラーを示すログが残っておりましたがこの文が意味するところをご教授いただけませんでしょうか？

  `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考記事: [Raspberry Pi • View topic - @reboot in crontab](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=116009)

Comment: 通信エラーの類ですね。ラズパイ環境のことはよくわからないのですが、@reboot は cron デーモンが起動した時に実行されると思います。そのタイミングで通信ができない状態だったと思われます。書かれてる内容だけだと対処方法はわかりませんが、案として思いつくのは、Cronデーモンの実行順序を後ろの方に下げてみると変化あるかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおりでcron実行時にネットワークの準備ができておらずエラーとなっておりました。 実行するタイミングを起動から遅らせるように調整したら解決いたしました。 今回はお知恵をお借りできたおかげで無事解決することができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

cron実行時にエラーなどあると、root にメールが届いている可能性があります。

通常メールは `/var/spool/mail/root` ファイルに保存されます。
もしファイルがあれば less などで内容確認してください。
cron実行時のエラーが出力されていれば それがヒントになります。

Answer (score 2):

cron の log を見ると、`@reboot` は機能しているようです。

まずは take88 さんの回答を支持しますが、もしそのファイルがなければ以下を試してみると良いと思います。

- 末尾の「`;`」を削除してみる

  この「`;`」が害になるとは思っていませんが、一応。
  これでダメなら、
- `@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/seminar/room-pub.py > /tmp/room-pub.log 2>&1` に変更してみる

  メールが届かないのであれば、このように標準出力と標準エラー出力をファイルに出力してみるのが良いでしょう。
  これで `/tmp/room-pub.log` が作成されていれば、この中に何らかのエラーが出力されていると思います。

---

コメントに対して回答です。

`Name or service not known` は、ホスト名が解決できない時によく見ます。
おそらく、room-pub.py 内でネットワークを使った何らかの処理をしているが、再起動直後でまだネットワークの準備ができておらず、DNS に問い合わせられない、といったところではないでしょうか?

Comment: ご指摘ありがとう御座います。回答が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。本文に追記もしましたが、  `@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/seminar/room-pub.py > /tmp/room-pub.log 2>&1`と設定すると、  `room-pub.log`に`socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`  と表示されるのですが、この意味を教えていただけないでしょうか？　@take88

Comment: @yottin 回答に追記しました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおりでcron実行時にネットワークの準備ができておらずエラーとなっておりました。  実行するタイミングを起動から遅らせるように調整したら解決いたしました。  今回はお知恵をお借りできたおかげで無事解決することができました。ありがとうございました。